# How to sort SQL query results if value is the same?

Tags: php, sql, database, sorting

I have a table (items) in my DB and it looks like this:

```
 --------------------------------------
| id | name | price | buyer | status   |
 --------------------------------------
| 1    item1    10     Bob   requested |
| 2    item2    20     Bob   requested |
| 3    item3    10     Tom   requested |
 --------------------------------------
```

I'm trying to query the data and then sort it, lump it together, and display it by name. If 2 names are the same it'll group it into one div in my HTML, and if they are different it'll group it into a different div. Basically each group of names is its own div whether there is 0 or 20 names that are the same. So far I queried my data like so

```
$request_data_query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM items WHERE status = 'requested' GROUP BY buyer");
$request_data_query->execute();

while($fetch = $request_data_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
```

then I was trying to compare results to see if they match

```
    if ($fetch['buyer'] === $fetch['buyer']) {
        //Same name HTML code here
    } else {
       // Single person HTML
    }
}
```

That code isn't sorting the way I thought it would. That prints 2 separate divs for the duplicate name and doesn't print the single person. I'm not quite sure what else to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this.  One that this isn't an exact match for your use, but is based on your examples.

```
// this goes before your loop
$previousBuyer = '';

// then inside your loop
if ($previousBuyer === $fetch['buyer']) {
    //Same name HTML code here
} else {
   // Single person HTML
}
$previousBuyer = $fetch['buyer'];
```

You'll need to account for the first buyer you check.